# Connection refused with java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am using a simple program to connect to a server:

Here is it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sentence;
        String modsent;

        //input Stream
        BufferedReader fromclient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //client Socket
        Socket clientsock = new Socket("stockholm.serverdhse2.se", 9000);
        //output Stream attached to socket
        DataOutputStream serverout = new DataOutputStream(clientsock.getOutputStream());
        //input from Server
        BufferedReader fromserver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsock.getInputStream()));

        sentence = fromclient.readLine();

        serverout.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");

        modsent = fromserver.readLine();

        System.out.println("From Server: " + modsent);

        clientsock.close();
    }

}
```

But right now I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at register.main(register.java:22)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have server at `"stockholm.serverdhse2.se", 9000`

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. Is this server active at all?

Comment: yes!!! That server definitely exists and is up!! Another question from me would be: How to send a String via the socket to the server?

Comment: From a command prompt try telnet stockholm.serverdhse2.se 9000 Any positive results? I can resolve and reach it from my location, but the port might be outwardly blocked from your location by a firewall or proxy?

Comment: From the PC the code is running on, using the account the code normally runs as, are you able to `telnet` to `stockholm.serverdhse2.se` (port 9000)? If you can't, then it's a network issue (firewall, port-forwarding, DNS, etc.), not a Java issue, and you might be better asking on ServerFault...

Comment: Make sure that the DNS address is resolvable. Your example URL is not in the public DNS system. Without a valid IP address Java isn't able to connect...

Comment: `DataOutputStream` is probably the wrong class to use for this, unless the server is also using Java. `new InputStreamReader(clientsock.getInputStream())` doesn't take encoding into account so your program won't be portable across operating systems

Comment: As for sending a string to the server, it's all up to the protocol that the server expects. You need to know that before you send data to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe its only reachable form a range dns server in your network , check with nmap:

nmap -A stockholm.serverdhse2.se -p 9000

wich give me a :

Failed to resolve given hostname/IP: stockholm.serverdhse2.se.

to make sure its a dns issue, try with the ip.
 If connects successfully with the ip you got it: "dns problem"